# Checking a checkbox didn't work on the second try

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, and when a user uploads a training document it will check the checkbox

```
$('#training_code_'+trainingCode).attr('checked','checked');
```

If the user deletes the training it will run this :

```
$('#training_code_'+trainingCode).removeAttr('checked');
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="training_code_1" id="training_code_1" 
<? if(mysql_num_rows($result_waperd)>0) echo"checked"; ?> disabled="disabled"/>
```

I tried to:

1. upload a file and it's checked.
2. delete the file and it's unchecked.
3. upload a file again and it still unchecked.

Does anyone know why that happens?

Comment: use `prop("checked", true)` and `prop("checked", false)`

Comment: use `.prop('checked', false/true)`

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle ? I don't see what the 1,2,3 points are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DOM properties like checked, disabled and readonly, the proper way to do this (as of JQuery 1.6) is to use prop.

```
$('#someid').prop('disabled', true);
```

so try (to check):

```
$('#training_code_'+trainingCode).prop('checked',true);
```

uncheck:

```
$('#training_code_'+trainingCode).prop('checked',false);
```